# QML GroupBox: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to load some QML form in QQuickWidget and keep getting: `QML GroupBox: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"`
The simplified QML is:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

GroupBox {
    id: root
    title: qsTr("1")

    Column {
        id: column1
        width: parent.width

        ComboBox {
            id: cbComboBox
            width: parent.width
            currentIndex: 0
            editable: false
        }

        GroupBox {
            id: groupBox
            title: "test"
            width: parent.width //the problem
            Label {
                text:"1"
                width: parent.width
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It looks like for some reason I can't use `parent.width` or `cbComboBox.width` for groupBox. And `root.width` works but too wide. What I'm missing? I need nested GroupBox to have maximum width (with spacing).

Comment: What version of Qt do you use?

Comment: I see that the problem is not the groupbox but the Column, it sets the width of the Column to a fixed value and you will see that it no longer throws the error.

Comment: @eyllanesc, 5.9.5

Comment: @eyllanesc, that helps, but 1) I don't understand the root of the problem 2) The new column width limits width of nested GroupBox. And I need it to be almost max. Actually whole QQuickWidget is placed in Vertically aligned panel that is resizable by width so I need widths of QML content to be non fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> According to the [Qt GroupBox QML Type documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-groupbox.html)
>
> > The implicit size of the GroupBox is calculated based on the size of its content.

It means the GroupBox will automatically use the size of its children to calculate its own size.
In your case, the only child is the Column whose width is equal to the GroupBox width. I think that is what's causing the binding loop.

If you set the width of the Column as said by @eyllanesc, the binding loop will disappear.

I would rather define the implicit width of the GroupBox (the width by default) in the QML part. In my example, the implicit width is 100px but it could be calculated from the widths of the children (ComboBox, other GroupBox,...).

```
// MyGroupBox.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

GroupBox {
    title: qsTr("1")
    implicitWidth: 100
    Column {
        id: column1
        width: parent.width
        ComboBox {
            id: cbComboBox
            currentIndex: 0
            editable: false
            width: parent.width
        }
        GroupBox {
            id: groupBox
            title: "test"
            width: parent.width
            Label {
                text: "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it will possible to set a real width depending on your project directly from the C++ by changing the width of the root object.

```
// main.cpp
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("://MyGroupBox.qml"));
    view->rootObject()->setWidth(800);
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This approach won't help in case on qml loaded via QQuickWidget... In this case qml's root item will be GroupBox and it can't use reference to `parent`. My current approach is to declare `Q_PROPERTY(int width READ width NOTIFY widthChanged)` and `signals:   void widthChanged();` in parent QWidget, then propagate pointer to it to QML with ```if (QQmlEngine* eng = quickWidget->engine()) {
        if (QQmlContext* cntx = eng->rootContext()) {
            cntx->setContextProperty("rootWidget", this);
        }
    }``` and then set in QML GroupBox's `width: rootWidget.width`

Comment: If you could update your answer with this or suggest better way in case of QQuickWidget I'll accept the answer.

Comment: My answer is updated considering the use of a QQuickWidget.